# how to make the nav bar flow smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When going from subject to subject on a nav bar, I want a drop-down menu of items but I want it to flow smoothly from one item to the other item instead of having it glitch for a second.

```
<nav class="navbar">
<div class="navbar_item" data-navitem="1">
<h3>Link 1</h3>
</div>
<div class="navbar_item" data-navitem="2">
<h3>Link 2</h3>
</div>
<div class="navbar_item" data-navitem="3">
<h3>Link 3</h3>
</div><div class="navbar_item" data-navitem="4">
<h3>Link 4</h3>
</div>

  <div class="navbar_item_subitem closed" data-subnavitem="1">
  <h1>Internal contnet</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar_item_subitem closed" data-subnavitem="2">
  <h1>Internal contnet 2</h1>
</div>



</nav>
```

css:

```
 .navbar_item{
 background-color: gray;
 width: 20%;
 float:left;
 }

.navbar_item_subitem
{
 overflow-y: hidden;
max-height: 100px; /* approximate max height */
width: 100%;
background: green;
height: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$('.navbar_item').hover(
function(){
$('.navbar_item_subitem').css('height',0);
var item = $(this).data("navitem");
$('.navbar_item_subitem[data-subnavitem='+item+']').animate({
  'height':'100'
}, 2000)

},
function(){
var item = $(this).data("navitem");
$('.navbar_item_subitem[data-subnavitem='+item+']').animate({
  'height':'0'
}, 500)
}
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n24ff6xq/

So I just want there to be a smoother flow between each link, instead of the white space that happens. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/n24ff6xq/1/

```
$('.navbar_item_subitem').animate({
      'height':'0'
}, 50);
```